# How to call a UIAlertView in nsobject class?

Tags: objective-c

Having trouble calling a ui alert view in a nsobject class. I wonder if im missing something. i get

```
cannot find protocol definition "UIAlertViewDelegate"
```

Thanks in advance..

**mynsobjectclass.h**

```
@interface mynsobjectclass : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>


@property (atomic, copy) NSString *serverURL
@end
```

**mynsobjectclass.m**

```
+(void)displayalert{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Hello there..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
    [alert show];


}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to check how you define your object of mynsobjectclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIAlertView is now deprecated UIAlertController should be used as of iOS 8. If you are targeting iOS 7 or below, UIAlertViewDelegate cannot be a delegate of an NSObject. It must be the delegate of a UIView/UIViewController since they are required to display the alert

Comment: I'm not sure where did you get that from. I have it working here!
I encapsulated UIAlertView, UIActionSheet and UIAlertController in a single object (inheriting from NSObject) and everything (displaying and calling back delegates) is working like a charm.